# How many times memcpy is called during System.out.println("hello")?

Tags: java, operating-system, memcpy

I think memcpy is called when constant string "hello" being copied from Java Heap(User space) to Kernel Space.

I think there's more, is there?

Comment: That completely depends on your JVM, but the answer will be "a lot".  And kernel space is not involved at all.

Comment: There are none. The string is translated to bytes, which isn't a memcpy. It is passed across the JNI interface, which isn't a memcpy. It is passed to the `write()` function, which isn't a memcpy.

Comment: can you list some of them? I think some of them are independent with JVM and sure to happen, are there?

Comment: Why do you think there are any at all? And why do you need to know?

Comment: @Slaks The kernel cannnot possibly print the characters without getting them into kernel space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could investigate it yourself. A starting point could be

**Foo.java**

```
class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("before");
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

compile it

```
javac Foo.java
```

then check for `memcpy` calls

```
ltrace -f -S -e memcpy java Foo 2>&1 \
    | sed -n "/before/,/hello/ {/\(before\|hello\|>memcpy\)/p}"
```

output

```
[pid 18509] write@SYS(1, "before", 6before)            = 6
[pid 18509] libjvm.so->memcpy(0x7fc2325f7410, 0xf341dec0, 1, 0xc0100800 ...
[pid 18509] libjvm.so->memcpy(0x7fc2325f73b0, 0xf341dec0, 11, 0xc0100800 ...
[pid 18509] write@SYS(1, "hello world", 11hello world)      = 11
```